# Step timeout is not set correctly or ignored

Tags: nunit, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a set of Selenium UI-tests run through VSTS on our build agent. They run just fine, but because UI-tests are inherently slow, we've set up a Release that runs at night - then spits out a detailed report for the testers to read in the morning. We're using NUnitTestAdapter.3.7.0 to run the tests.

Because of the long run-time I have the Step-timeout for the "Test Assemblies"-step where these tests live set to 0 (unlimited). Pretty straight forward right? However, for some unknown reason, the step still gets cancelled after an hour - cutting off a large set of the tests. Now I suppose I could create smaller sets of tests and add more similar "Test Assemblies"-steps, but that doesn't seem right to me.

The .trx log show the tests run for roughly an hour before being cancelled:

```
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9610971Z ##[section]Starting: Test Assemblies
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z ==============================================================================
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Version      : 1.0.85
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=624539)
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z ==============================================================================
2017-06-21T03:02:36.9767239Z Preparing task execution handler.
2017-06-21T03:02:37.3267423Z Executing the powershell script: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\1.0.85\VSTest.ps1
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z Working folder: C:\agent\_work\r17\a
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "xxx.dll" /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=MP2" /Settings:"C:\agent\_work\r17\a\TestResults\1_2017-06-21_05-02-37-AM.runsettings" /logger:trx /TestAdapterPath:"C:\agent\_work\r17\a\drop\b\packages\NUnit3TestAdapter.3.7.0\tools"
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.25420.1
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z 
2017-06-21T03:02:38.0298958Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2017-06-21T03:02:38.1705198Z Information: NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test execution started
2017-06-21T03:02:38.1705198Z 

....

2017-06-21T04:01:16.0450600Z ##[warning]No results found to publish.
2017-06-21T04:01:16.2950650Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2017-06-21T04:01:16.3106930Z ##[section]Finishing: Test Assemblies
```

Am I missing something here? Is there a hard upper limit to these steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please trouble shooting the issue with below aspects (based on you are using your private agent):

1. Check if the related build was succeed: test results were published successful and test assemblies were copied in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.
2. Make sure you have **publish Artifacts** task in the related build definition.
3. Check subfolder in `C:\agent\_work\r17\a` to find if the test assemblies exist.
4. For 60 min timeout for release, since your Test Assemblies step has already set timeout as 0, you should check the agent setting in your release definition to check if the **Deployment timeout** set as 60.

[image]

Comment: It indeed seems to be a (well hidden) separate Agent Setting within the Release Definition. Maybe VSTS should hint towards this somewhere?